Storing data and retrieving data at misaglined addresses (C/C++)
I'm building a custom memory heap (as a fun side-project) in C/C++ to efficiently provide access to reusable regions of memory. For this, I'm investigating whether I can store and retrieve values at (what I assume to be) misaligned memory addresses using reinterpret_cast and some pointer hacks.
I can't find a clear answer elsewhere on StackOverflow (or the search engines are failing me).
The simplified C/C++ code of what I'm planning to do conceptually:
    unsigned char chars[10] = {0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0};
    uint64_t val = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(chars + 1);
    std::cout << "val: " << val << std::endl; // on my machine correctly gives 18446744073709551615

std::string* myString = new std::string("Hello world!");
    *reinterpret_cast<std::string**>(chars + 1) = myString;
    std::string* retrievedPtr = *reinterpret_cast<std::string**>(chars + 1);
    std::cout << "retrievedStr: " << *retrievedPtr << std::endl; // Correctly prints 'Hello world!'

I'm planning on doing this with only basic numeric types (char, long, int, raw pointers etc.) so no constructors/destructors are involved.
Can anyone confirm if the above code is "safe" and if not, then why not? And is this even considered memory misalignment?

What CPU are you planning to run this on?

@DanMašek 64-bit x86 machines, but the question applies to any arbitrary CPU architecture. In the code example, uint64_t is just an example but should not be taken too literally.

Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062894/take-advantage-of-arm-unaligned-memory-access-while-writing-clean-c-code  Also note that the rules will probably be different for C and C++.

On some systems you'll have a performance hit to handle the misalignment. On some systems the program will go boom! On some systems you might not see any problems whatsoever.

@RichardCritten That's a very interesting read, thank you for linking it. I think I got my answer there. Much appreciated!
Also some immediate good inspiration of what I can do myself in order to deal with these cases.

@ImJustACowLol -->  reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*> is not "safe".  Using a union of char, long, int, raw pointers will work in C though.

@chux-ReinstateMonica would that mean that in my example, instead of having 'char[] chars[10]' I would have 'SomeUnion[] union[10]'?

Something like union u { char chars[10]; uint64_t u54; long L; int i; void * ptr; }; union u x = {  {0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0} };.

Both reinterpret_casting arbitrary pointers and union type-punning result in undefined behavior in C++.  If you want to create an object in pre-allocated uninitialized storage then you should use placement-new.  If you want to read arbitrary bytes as some type of object then you should use std::bit_cast or std::copy).

FYI, the C language doesn't have: reinterpret_cast, std::bit_cast, std:::copy.  Change your tags and question to remove the C language.

@ThomasMatthews The title and tags are fine. A cast in a C file (for example (int*)) is equivalent to a reinterpret_cast<int*>(...) in a C++ file. The same principles  and theory apply. I'll keep the title and tags the way they are.
