# How does the Linux kernel temporarily disable x86 SMAP in copy_from_user?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, x86, operating-system, kernel

I want to know how the Linux kernel disables x86 SMAP when executing the `copy_from_user()` function. I tried to find something in source code, but I failed.

[Supervisor Mode Access Prevention (SMAP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervisor_Mode_Access_Prevention) is a security feature of x86 CPUs to prevent the kernel from accessing unintended user-space memory, which helps to fend off various exploits.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you can show me the related codes

Comment: Could you please expand the "SMAP" acronym?

Comment: Supervisor Mode Access Prevention (SMAP) is a security featureof Intel CPUs to prevent the kernel from accessing unintended user-space memory and in turn helping fend off various exploits.

Comment: copy_from_user function copies data from user space to kernel space, but with SMAP protection, in kernel space to access a user space memory is illegal. So when really copies datas, the kernel will temporarily disable SMAP protection so that data can be transfered from user space, and when transfer done, the SMAP protection will be enabled again.

Comment: more infomation can be seen in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervisor_Mode_Access_Prevention

Comment: This is a very broad question since the answer depends on the architecture. Are you talking about a specific architecture (e.g. x86)? If so, please state it in the question. If not, then it's definitely too broad to answer: every architecture that supports SMAP has its own way of enabling/disabling it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have updated the description of the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As documented in the Wikipedia page that you linked:

> SMAP is enabled when memory paging is active and the SMAP bit in the CR4 control register is set. SMAP can be temporarily disabled for explicit memory accesses by setting the EFLAGS.AC (Alignment Check) flag. The `stac` (Set AC Flag) and `clac` (Clear AC Flag) instructions can be used to easily set or clear the flag.

The Linux kernel does exactly this to temporarily disable SMAP: it uses `stac` to set EFLAGS.AC before copying the data, and then uses `clac` to clear EFLAGS.AC when done.

[The AC flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) has existed since 486 as [alignment check for user-space load/store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837550/prohibit-unaligned-memory-accesses-on-x86-x86-64); SMAP overloads the meaning of that flag bit.  [`stac`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/stac)/[`clac`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/clac) are new with SMAP and are only allowed in kernel mode (CPL=0); they fault in user-space (and on CPUs without SMAP, also in kernel mode).

---

In theory it's pretty simple, but in practice the Linux kernel codebase is a jungle of functions, macros, inline assembly templates, etc. To find out exactly how this is done we can look at the source code, starting from [`copy_from_user()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/uaccess.h#L141):

1. When `copy_from_user()` is called, it makes a quick check to see if the memory range is valid, then calls [`_copy_from_user()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/uaccess.h#L107)...
2. ... which does another couple of checks and then calls [`raw_copy_from_user()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_64.h#L66)...
3. ... which, before doing the actual copy, calls [`__uaccess_begin_nospec()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h#L122)...
4. ... which is just a macro that expands to `stac(); barrier_nospec()`.
5. Focusing on [`stac()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/arch/x86/include/asm/smap.h#L50), which is a simple inline function, we have:

   ```
    alternative("", __ASM_STAC, X86_FEATURE_SMAP);
   ```

The [`alternative()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/arch/s390/include/asm/alternative.h#L141) macro is a pretty complicated macro for selecting alternatives for an instruction at kernel boot time, based on CPU support. You can check the source file in which it is defined for a bit more information. In this case it is used to decide whether the kernel needs to use the `stac` instruction or not, based on CPU support (old x86 CPUs do not have SMAP available, and therefore don't have the instruction: on those CPUs this just becomes a no-op).

Looking at the [`__ASM_STAC`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/arch/x86/include/asm/smap.h#L17) macro we see:

```
#define __ASM_STAC  ".byte 0x0f,0x01,0xcb"
```

Which is the assembled `stac` opcode in bytes. This is defined with the `.byte` directive instead of the mnemonic because, again, this needs to compile even on old toolchains where the version of binutils doesn't know about those instructions.

Once at boot, the `cpuid` instruction is used to check for `X86_FEATURE_SMAP` (bit 20 of `ebx` when `cpuid` is executed with `eax=7, ecx=0` to get the [extended features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D7.2C_ECX.3D0:_Extended_Features)), and this tells the kernel whether SMAP is available (rewrite the machine code to make the instruction become `stac`) or not (keeping a no-op).

Once done with all of this madness (which really all just boils down to *a single instruction*), the actual copy from user memory is performed, and the [`__uaccess_end()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h#L121) macro is then used to re-enable SMAP. This macro uses `alternative()` in the same way as the one we just saw, and ends up executing `clac` (or a `nop`).

Comment: You edited out the "for some reason" comment on `stac` / `clac` only being available on CPL0.  It does bear comment since you can do the same thing in any mode with `pushf`/`popf`.  If I had to guess, it's for performance, so `stac` can just toggle permission checking if SMAP's enabled, never alignment checking.  (The alignment check effect of AC only applies to user-space, CPL3).  IDK if it or popf serialize loads/stores; they might if the SMAP status is renamed.