# Why processor read only aligned addresses

Tags: memory, alignment, cpu-architecture, memory-alignment, processor

So I was reading few articles (and few questions on StackOverflow) about memory alignment and I understood why structs like this:

```
struct A
{
  char c;
  int i;
}
```

will have padding.
Also it is clear that fetches from not aligned memory will be slower if processor can read only from aligned offsets.

But why processor can read only from aligned memory? Why it can't just read data from random address? You know, from Random-Access Memory...

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is memory alignment required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881179/why-is-memory-alignment-required), according to the OP who posted an answer saying that Q&A was what they were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Processors are optimized to most common usecase: when data is correctly aligned. This is a reason why aligned reads are preferred.

But this doesn't answer your question. What makes aligned read more effective?

Answer is, that modern processors don't like to read from memory. They read from their cache which is in orders of magnitude faster.

Those caches organized using *cache lines*. Typical cache line is 64 byte and it is always aligned to its size, you can read exact values [here](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen#Memory_Hierarchy). When you read aligned value, there is guarantee that value which size less or equal to cache line would be in single cache line. For unaligned value it is possible that part of the value in cache while other part accessible only from RAM.

### UPDATE: More detailed explanation.

Consider such code running on modern x86_64 processor with 64 byte cache lines:

```
movq rax, qword ptr [rdi]
```

It is reading 64 bit number from pointer `rdi` to the register `rax`.

If `rdi` is properly aligned (meaning it is divisible by 8), it is guaranteed to be in single cache line. See diagram with visualization of all 8 possible locations:

```
  CACHE LINE
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  0 <- offset       8                 16                24                |
| +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+  |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  |
| +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-- +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-- +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-- +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--  |
|                                                                          |
|  32                36                44                52                |
| +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+  |
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  |
| +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-- +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-- +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-- +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--  |
|                                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So in case of cache miss, it would be limited to single one because when cache is fetched, it fetches whole 8 bytes of our value at once.

With misaligned value, we can have situation like this:

```
+--------------------+------------------+
|Cache line 1        | Cache line 2     |
|            +-+-+-+---+-+-+-+          |
|            | | | | | | | | |          |
|            +-+-+-+---+-+-+-+          |
|                    |                  |
+--------------------+------------------+
```

If our value crosses boundary between cache lines, CPU would need to load twice more data from memory (2 whole cache lines).

Same thing applies to page faults though chances of a particular read causing a 2 TLB misses quite rare, I expect.

Also, when you do memory *writes* to misaligned value, it can be even worse because there are protocols of CPU cache invalidation, and such writes would invalidate *both* cache lines. It would be worse if such cache line is often accessed from multiple threads. In fact, many efficient synchronization mechanisms that use atomic integers often align them to the 64bit alignment to avoid unnecessary cache invalidations.

See, for example, crossbeams [CachePadded](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.4/crossbeam/utils/struct.CachePadded.html).

Comment: This also doesn't explain the problem. Yes, processor uses 64-byte cache lines, but the cache is initially read from memory, so why not read 64 bytes into cache from an unaligned address?

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko I updated my answer to add more details. In short: cache lines are always have same alignment as their size. This greatly reduces amount of memory in CPU needed to store data about which memory addresses is cached. By factor of 64 with 64 bytes cache lines, in fact.

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like alignment wouldn't be required without cache.  That's kind of the opposite: an external bus makes it even *more* desirable to omit the byte-within-word address lines, and would make the relevant boundary-crossing chunk size for a penalty being unavoidable be 8 bytes, not 64.  See the accepted answer on [Why is memory alignment required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12881179) describing a memory bus as a matrix of 1-bit cells that each respond separately to an address.

Comment: Within one cache line on modern x86, yes CPUs spend the transistors to support unaligned load/store at full efficiency when it doesn't cross a cache line, but this is expensive.  Many CPUs with caches don't do that, notably MIPS which didn't support misaligned accesses until the last few embedded revisions, decades after the original design.  And see [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217528) re: ECC granules for writing to L1d cache.

Answer (score 0):

I depends upon the processor. Some processors do not allow unaligned accesses at all. Other processors can, but it tends to be slower.

In your example (if the fields are packed and unaligned access it permitted, if the processor tries to read i, it usually takes fetches from memory to get it.

Some processors take the performance hit of multiple accesses to retrieve unaligned data. Others simply do not allow it.

Comment: Yes, but why processors need to fetch multiple time when address is unaligned? RAM is just set of transistors, so why it can't read data to register from any address?