# Can someone please explain the results returned by 'sizeof' in this code

Tags: c++, padding, packing

I don't undertand the output shown below.

I know that whenever a virtual function is present it creates a `vptr` but still the size printed is more than I would expect:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

class Base
{
 int x;
 int y;
 int z;
public:
 virtual void fun(){}
 virtual void fun2(){}
};

class Derived:public Base
{
 public:
  void fun() override {} 
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  cout<<sizeof(Base)<<endl;
  cout<<sizeof(Derived)<<endl;
  cout<<sizeof(int)<<endl; 
}
```

> 24
>   24
>   4
>   [Finished in 0.3s]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I think so there is no padding occur

Comment: `sizeof(Base) = sizeof(void *) + sizeof(int) * 3` aligned to `sizeof(void *)` which is 8 bytes.

Comment: @hauron Whoops!  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this a 64 bit build?  If so, `sizeof Base` would be:

> 8 (vtable pointer) + (3 * 4 = 12) (member variables) + 4 (pad to multiple of 8 bytes) 
>   = 24

Since `Derived` derives only from `Base` and adds no member variables, its size is the same.

Why is padding added?  To maintain 8-byte alignment in arrays and on the stack.  Why is that important? That's a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496848/does-unaligned-memory-access-always-cause-bus-errors/1496881#1496881).

Comment: Why not?  What should it be?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Motion to strike 'typical' :)